# Applying multiple regression results to new data SPSS

Tags: regression, spss, prediction

My study involves testing infants at multiple time points using a number of behavioural tests.

I used a multiple regression to establish which behavioural variables could predict severity of outcome score at the end of the testing.

So, I tested infants at 14 months and used a regression model to identify whether scores from any of the behavioural variables could predict better or worse scores at 24 months.

my model works fine and 4 IV's significantly predicted severity of outcome. But now I want to use this regression model to see whether it can predict 24m outcomes from a new dataset with new infants - BUT they have been tested on the same IV's and DV's.

Does anyone know how I might go about doing this in SPSS?

Thank you!!

Comment: I don't quite follow this. Can you provide more information about the variables & the model? Note that 'how do I do ___ in SPSS?' questions are off topic here, but there may be a statistical question we can help you with.

Comment: I ran a multiple regression using behavioural data from infants.  The IV's were behavioural measures (all continuous) and I used scores from these measures to predict whether an infant had a higher or lower general ability score later in development. 
The model showed that the scores from 4 behavioural measures predicted ability score later on.  I now have a second phase of infants that have been tested on the same measures and have later ability scores.  I want to use the new data in the original regression model to see if the model can accurately predict ability scores of the new infants

Comment: and wanted to know if this was possible as i only use SPSS

Answer (score 3):

You need to take the parameters from one regression, and apply them to a new dataset. There is more than one way to do this in SPSS. Here's the easiest way (that I know of), but see @JKP's answer for another way.

You merge the two datasets, with a flag variable saying which dataset they were from. All the variables have the same name EXCEPT the outcome variable.

For the 24 month dataset, set the value of the outcome to missing.

Run your regression, and save the predicted values. Because the new dataset cases are missing on the outcome, they have no effect on the regression model. But if they are not missing on all of the predictors, they will get a predicted value. You can compare this predicted value with the actual values, for dataset 2.

This is somewhat easier in SAS, R, or Stata - as all of these easily store regression results and allow them to be applied to a new dataset. You can do that in SPSS using the ODS system, but it's fiddly.

In Stata, run your regression, load your new data, type:

```
predict predvalues
```

In SAS, use Proc Score (takes too long to explain, Google will help you).

In R, use:

```
 dataSet2$predvalues <- predict(RegModel, newdata=dataSet2)
```

Comment: hanks everyone! I think what I am trying to say is that I want to add the IV and constant coefficients from the first regression into the new model. So I want to actually get the significance of the new regression that has the new data and old coefficients) and the significant predictors, like the output that you normally get in spss? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the easiest way is to save the regression model as an xml (pmml) file when you run it and then use the scoring wizard on Utilities to generate the scoring code.  The scoring is actually done with a COMPUTE using the APPLYMODEL function, but the scoring wizard will generate this code for you.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's been a while since I've used SPSS, I didn't know about that one.

Comment: thanks everyone!

I think what I am trying to say is that I want to add the IV and constant coefficients from the first regression into the new model.  So I want to actually get the significance of the new regression that has the new data and old coefficients) and the significant predictors, like the output that you normally get in spss?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't do that (if I've understood you correctly). If you take the estimates, and then say that they are fixed for a new dataset, then they have no variance (because you fixed them), and if they don't have variance, they don't have standard errors or p-values. You can see if the coefficients differ in the new data, if that helps.

Comment: so I have data from the first regression saying that infant language scores and communication scores taken at 14 months can predict how well a child scores on overall IQ at 24 months of age.

I now have new data using the same scoring method and I wanted to use a new regression but multiplying the coefficients of each IV from the original model to each new corresponding IV in the new data, so that i can test whether this model works with new infants.  so I thought the coefficients from the first model would represent extent of the change in outcome for the new IV's?

Comment: i'm not sure how best to explain it.  I was told that I could just "plug in" each coefficient and multiply it by the corresponding IV in the new data and then run this model in order to test whether the original model can successfully predict all infants or if it was just a fluke that it works the first time

Comment: I think you are saying that you just want to use the coefficients estimated in the first dataset to predict values on new data but using the same variables.  You can do that as suggested above and then look at correlations or other measures.